# Trying to beta distribute a native script build using crashlytics

Tags: nativescript, crashlytics

To distribute a build with crashlytics the documentation at:

https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html

States that I need to execute

```
gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

How would i go about doing this with nativescript.

The build command is

```
tns build android --release
```

The above command is essentially `gradle assembleRelease` plus whatever native needs to do.

How do I append the `crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease` task to the `tns build` command?

I have seen this documentation in nativescript:
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/gradle-hooks

I am not sure how to use the gradle-hooks to do this.

Comment: Crashlytics is already part of Firebase, you may follow the setup guide in the [Firebase plugin docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/CRASHREPORTING.md).

Comment: I would like to upload a distribution to crashlytics for Beta distribution.

The gradle task needs to executed to upload the build.